# How to make llvm IR code run in c?

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I want a c program to execute a function using llvm IR instead of the c code.
Is it possible?
I do not want to convert the entire module.
Only one function needs to be called in the end.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call LLVM Jit from c program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838304/call-llvm-jit-from-c-program)

Comment: I have tried that.Could someone possibly add the changes for it to work in llvm 3.5.

Comment: StackOverflow is about concrete problems. What is the problem with that solution?

Comment: The code does not work in llvm 3.5.Some headers have changed probably.It would be nice if a solution is added for the latest version.

Comment: maybe you want to read chapter 4 of the kaleidoscope example http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl4.html it demonstrates how to use MCJIT to JIT llvm IR and call it.